# Haskell Chart package- error in plotting the chart

Tags: haskell, charts, plot

I  have the following Haskell code with me.

```
import Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Simple

range, data1, data2 :: [Double]
range = [0..10]
data1 = [1,4,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,1]
data2 = [1,2,2,7,4,3,7,1,3,1]

main = plotPDF "chart-example.pdf" range data1 Solid data2 Solid
```

I get the below error on executing it. anyone who can help me to resolve it.

[image]

Comment: You can install old versions of a package simply with `cabal install chart-0.17`.

Comment: I installed version 0.17. still the same error is there.

Answer (score 2):

`Chart-1.1` seems to be broken. The only instance of `PlotPDFType` is

```
instance (PlotArg a, PlotPDFType r) => PlotPDFType (a -> r)
```

This is a recursive instance, but there's no base case!

The `IO` instance is still there in version 0.17. Maybe you can go back to that version. And you should file a bug here: https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/issues

Comment: can you pls tell me how to install version 0.17 ?

Comment: @user3032393 cabal install Chart-0.17

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed in the new 1.2 release of the library. The Simple API (which this example requires) is now in it's own package: Chart-simple-1.2.